# Why does Salesforce consider this simple parent-to-child relationship SOQL query not valid?

Tags: salesforce, relationship, many-to-one, soql

A CaseMilestone record can have one Case record and one Case record can have many CaseMilestone records.

So this works:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM CaseMilestones) FROM Case
```

Similarly, a CaseMilestone record can have one MilestoneType record and one MilestoneType record can have many CaseMilestone records, but the following doesn't work:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM CaseMilestones) FROM MilestoneType
```

How come? If it is because not all CaseMilestones are required to have an associated MilestoneType, which query will get me what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check "Child Relationship Name" in Lookup from CaseMilestones to MilestoneType
and change to `SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM "Child Relationship Name") FROM MilestoneType`